# How do I allow users to execute commands via ssh without allocating a pseudo-terminal

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to allow users to run a limited set of commands.

But not to allow them to create interactive sessions.

Just like GitHub does.

If you try to ssh without a command it greetings you and close the session.

I can acquire this by using `ForceCommand some-script`

But getting in  `some-script` i then need to eval user's input.

Perhaps any other `NoTTY`-like option in sshd_config?

--- UPDATE ---

i'm looking for a pure `SSH` / `Bash` solution, not Perl/Python/etc. hacks.

Comment: Not allocating a terminal is not the same as restricting what can be done. If you want to read interactive input you need a terminal.

Comment: ok, how do i close the connection if user did not provide any command? like: `ssh user@host ls` will execute `ls` on remote host, but `ssh user@host` will close the connection without execute anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track with setting `ForceCommand` to a script. You need to then inspect the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable, which contains the actual command which the user provided to the SSH client. For example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    date)
        date
        ;;
    fortune)
        fortune
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Valid commands are: date, fortune"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

The user can then execute commands like this:

```
% ssh localhost fortune 
Q:   How much does it cost to ride the Unibus?
A:      2 bits.
```

If the user doesn't provide a command they should get an error message from the script (and the connection terminated):

```
% ssh localhost
Valid commands are: date, fortune, rev
Connection to localhost closed.
```

**Edit:** It is possible to disable a terminal in [authorized_keys](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sshd.8.html#contenttoc6) when using key authentication:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/restricted.sh",no-pty ssh-rsa AAA...
```

Comment: yep, i already have this working. i just wonder if i can do the same without `ForceCommand`. I were sure there are an option in sshd like `DisableTTY` or something. Just can not recall its name and can not find in man pages, grrr....

Comment: yea, `no-pty` is the option i were looking for. but i want to set it in sshd_config, not in authorized_keys, before each key. this becomes hairy :)

Comment: @DaniEl It doesn't look like it.

Comment: ok, it does not, but i yet want to set this option in sshd_config. Is this doable? `NoPTY` does not seem to work

Comment: @DaniEl I don't think it's possible. There's no real problem with allocating PTYs however.

Comment: possibly i missundertood your response, sorry. So, "It doesn't look like it" meant i can not have `no-pty` option in sshd_config? sorry for the mess... :)

Comment: @DaniEl Correct, I meant that as far as I can tell it's not possible to set `no-pty` globally in `sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow `git` commands, set the user's shell to `git-shell` with the following command:

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/git-shell <USERNAME>
```

`git-shell` is part of the git package.

If you want to allow arbitrary commands, [mgorven's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/441115/26130) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the `sshd` man page in the `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT` section. I think you are looking for `no-pty` option.

Comment: oh yes, that's it, `no-pty`, i confused it with `no-tty` :) ok, any way to set it in sshd_config rather than per key?

Answer (score -3):

Take a look on this script:

http://lists.fusionforge.org/pipermail/fusionforge-general/2012-May/001795.html

It's a perl script restricting the commands...

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and link elsewhere for more detail.

Comment: Well.. it's just a simple script that can be use to restrict shell commands. To use, you just have to put this script as the shell script in /etc/password

Comment: Right. Your answer still has zero content. What happens when that link goes dead? Your answer is worthless. Again, provide some content here, making sure to link to the original source for attribution and more detail.

Comment: Ok, some contents from Roland Mas